# Why don't UIKit methods utilize NS_REQUIRES_SUPER?

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

Plenty of `UIKit` classes can be subclassed, but the documentation asks that certain methods, if overridden, must be sure to still call up to `super`. For example:

```
-[UIViewController viewWillAppear:]
-[UITableViewCell didTransitionToState:]
<every method UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition declares>
```

Why has Apple elected not to append [`NS_REQUIRES_SUPER`](http://llvm.org/klaus/clang/commit/90ec5ff217d0a13279483131d463b2f55ebaf2f3/) to the declarations of these methods, since they do indeed "require super"? My first thought was backwards-compatibility with earlier versions of clang, but even that's not an issue, I think, after reading the following clang documentation excerpt:

> Note that on both OS X and iOS that the Foundation framework provides a
>   convenience macro `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER` that provides syntactic sugar for this
>   attribute:
>
> `- (void)foo NS_REQUIRES_SUPER;`
>
> This macro is conditionally defined depending on the compiler's support for
>   this attribute.  If the compiler does not support the attribute the macro
>   expands to nothing.

Comment: This question can only truly be answered by the people responsible for those APIs.  It's a mistake to think of Apple as a single responsible party.  Individual developers wrote those APIs and some of them might not know about `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER` or simply forgot about it.  Anyway, the first two you mentioned predate `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER` so perhaps they simply haven't gotten around to annotating those two yet, or they aren't annotating them to avoid breaking source code that happens to work in spite of not calling super.

Comment: What Rob said, a possible solution though would be https://gist.github.com/steipete/5626678

Comment: I believe that instead of forcing the developer to call `super`, they have decided to rewrite API. Ideally, when overriding a method which is made to be overriden, you shouldn't have to call `super`. Note that all `UIViewController.viewWill/Did...` methods currently say "default does nothing" or "default is nop". This is a better solution than just marking the method with a compiler flag. However, also note that when overriding a method, you should (almost) always call `super`; that means they would have to add the flag basically to every method in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a relatively new annotation, and people haven't done the work to apply it to the (huge) api.